# Pass down props as a parameter to another HoC within compose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am using the recompose library and have a bunch of HoCs building on each other, one of each needs previous props as a parameter. This is what is looks like:

```
export default compose(
  withSomeHoC(param1, param2),
  withAnotherHoc(myFunction.bind(undefined, requiredValuePassedAsPropsFromWithSomeHoC)),
)(MyComponent)
```

So as you can see the parameter required for `withAnotherHoC` must come from the props. But I don't know how I can get it. Here is what I've already tried:

Just using an arrow function hoping they will be passed in:

```
export default compose(
  withSomeHoC(param1, param2),
  (ownerProps) => withAnotherHoc(myFunction.bind(undefined, ownerProps.myRequiredParam))
)(MyComponent)
```

Using the `withProps` function:

```
export default compose(
  withSomeHoC(param1, param2),
  withProps(ownerProps => withAnotherHoc(myFunction.bind(undefined, ownerProps.myRequiredParam)))
)(MyComponent)
```

None of these work so far, so how can I accomplish this?

I do suppose one of the reasons for my troubles is because I do not quite understand how the props are passed down, so my apologies if this is just something silly on my part.

Comment: What's `myFunction`? Please, provide all relevant code. Since the problem can occur on your side in any listed HOC, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary.

Comment: it shouldn't be relevant to the problem, but `myFunction` does a GET call and the parameter which I need to come from the props is the id I am fetching the objects from.
The relevant part of this is just how I can access the props for me to use it as parameters in `myFunction`

Comment: And what about function's return value? At which point should it be used by a component?

Comment: The function's return value is just an object which I would like to pass in as another prop to be passed down into the component.

Comment: All of this is handled in another HoC inside `withAnotherHoC`, which is working just fine. The problem here is just accessing those props for `myFunction`'s parameter

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with customized HOC:

```
const myHoc = Comp => props => {
  const CompWithAnotherHoc = withAnotherHoc(myFunction(props.myRequiredParam))(Comp);
  return <CompWithAnotherHoc ...props />;
};

export default compose(
  withSomeHoC(param1, param2),
  myHoc
)(MyComponent)
```